# Override header Content and adding block

Tags: layout, configuration, xml, header, magento-2.1.2

I have extended LUMA theme and want to customize header.

I want to add static block before logo and want to move logo to center of page which is on left side.

Final result will be

> [1] static block [2] logo (in center) [3] Search form (this is already
>   on correct position).

Please advice how to achieve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can do this by putting DIV over your logo and search box**

Also create a "container" for your static block (inside this you can call your static block)  in `logo.phtml`.

Now assign a class to each container and give them required width and float them accordingly .

So it will look like `1) Static block 2)  Logo 3) Search`

I hope someone else will get idea from here , as I am posting late on question .

Answer (score 10):

you use **referenceBlock** `logo`

```
<referenceBlock name="logo">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test_links">
          <arguments>
           <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">test_links</argument>
          </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Where to add this. I have also extended LAYOUT and this should be added in layout/default.xml (i think)

Comment: @Jai yes default will do that.

Comment: Added static block with "testblock" identifier in admin. Added above lines replacing testblock in default.xml. Deployed, Upgraded, flushed but but didint work :(

Comment: did you add `<body></body>` tag

Comment: Yes .Here is all code of extended default.xml: 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="testblock">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="testblock" xsi:type="string">testblock</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

        </referenceBlock>



    </body>
</page>

Comment: @Jai missed the `before="-"` now check and check in error log maybe error their  `<page xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/La‌​yout/etc/page_config‌​uration.xsd"> <body> <referenceBlock name="logo"> <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="testblock" before="-"> <arguments> <argument name="testblock" xsi:type="string">testblock</argument> </arguments> </block> </referenceBlock> </body> </page>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49771/discussion-between-jai-and-fme-extensions).

Comment: I added post in discussion. Please have a look at it